# why pip's cache not working when try again using sudo?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I'm using pip to install package X, as follows:

```
pip3 install --upgrade X
```

After running, pip says that it needs root access to install this package as follows:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages'
```

So, I have to re-run the command using sudo:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade X
```

The problem is that pip start to download the package again. Why it does not leverage the cache?

Comment: Because `sudo` runs in a different shell environment

Comment: Why aren't you using a virtualenv, though?

Comment: I want to use this package in different projects, should I have to install it in a virtualenv?

Comment: You can use one virtualenv for all projects, or one per project. The point is that you won't get permission denied by your OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virtualenv` is a good idea as @cricket_007 points out in comment. For your question why pip does not use the cache when you re-run it with `sudo`, that's because the cache directory is related with the user who owns the running process. More specific for Unix and MacOS, it's:

- Unix: `~/.cache/pip and it respects the XDG_CACHE_HOME directory.`
- macOS: `~/Library/Caches/pip`

You can find more details at [cache docs of pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#caching), or explore the source code at [user_cache_dir](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/utils/appdirs.py#L14). So when you retry with `sudo`, the cache directory is expanded to `/root/.cache`